# Boxplot giving only points and no boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have plotted two boxplots side by side from two different datasets in the same plot. I made some transformations first they had different number of observations.

```
d <- rbind(cbind(stack(nyclimate2009.short), group='A'), 
           cbind(stack(nyclimate2019.short), group='B'))
   

head(d)
  values                ind group
1      0 nyclimate2009$SNOW     A
2     NA nyclimate2009$SNOW     A
3     NA nyclimate2009$SNOW     A
4      0 nyclimate2009$SNOW     A
5     33 nyclimate2009$SNOW     A
6      0 nyclimate2009$SNOW     A

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(group, values)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ind, scales='free_y')
```

However the boxplots are coming out as points only and no box in it. Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 2 points in the dataset?